# A VS 2008 code snippet doesn't get inserted fully

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

I have the Javascript one liner below as a code snippet in VS 2008 SP1. When I insert it in the code (C#) window, only 'var SelectedVal =' gets inserted, instead of the whole statement.

Also.. is there a way to get the Insert Snippet to show up in the context menu when in aspx editor window?

Code Snippet:
var SelectedVal = $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>').val();

Comment: Can you post the whole snippet please?

Comment: It's just that one line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394(v=vs.90).aspx) or [ASP.NET web forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k33801s3(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)? Your code snippet there seems to be from asp.net. If that's the case, you don't seem to need the #. Like so:

```
 var name= '<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>';
 var SelectedVal = $(name).val();
```